# How to stop vertical Scrolling OnSortCol event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have jqgrid with pretty basic configuration. When I'm sorting the columns if the page is scrolled down , the `onSortCol` event is scrolling the grid to the top of the page.

I'm writing this piece of code

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    //other parameters of jqGrid like colModel
    onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) 
    {("#list").scrollTop=50;}
});
```

Basically I am trying to pull it down. Bit its not working.
I dont know how to use event.preventDefault() here as this event does not accept the event param.
I have also tried setthis scrollTop property in load and gridcomplete, does not help?

Can you give me some suggestions ?

Comment: As far as I understand you want after sorting a column to stay in the same vertical position?

Comment: @Tony Tomov you are right, I dont want the div to scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: I have tried to get the scrollTop value of the grid it is 0 when the page is scrolleddown.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? I can't reproduce the problem. After scrolling to some position and perform a sort the position of the div is the same.  You can see this is all [demos here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/) The only way this not to work is if you use virtual scrolling. Please let us know which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: Thanks @TonyTomov for the demos.Actually I am drawing the jqgrid based on a search. Before that it the div is hidden. On Succes of search it is getting visible. I am calling an api to load the data, so everytime I do a event in grid it results in a api call.

Comment: Can you please post a demo of this?